# Adding the new column based on existing column in dataframe giving NaN values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to add the column based on dataframe's existing column. Frame contains 5 columns. I need to replace the category column by numeric values. Based on this I need to add `'Class'` column and assign the values 0 or 1 according to the condition as mentioned.

```
Desired result:
        File         Task  Category  Class
0    g0pA_taska.txt    a      0       0
1    g0pA_taskb.txt    b      3       1
2    g0pA_taskc.txt    c      2       1
3    g0pA_taskd.txt    d      1       1
4    g0pA_taske.txt    e      0       0
...
...
99   orig_taske.txt    e     -1      -1
 plagiarism_df.replace({'Category' : {'non':0,'heavy':1,'light':2,'cut':3,'orig':-1}})
    plagiarism_df.loc[plagiarism_df['Category']==0, 'Class'] = 0
    plagiarism_df.loc[plagiarism_df['Category']==1, 'Class'] = 1
    plagiarism_df.loc[plagiarism_df['Category']==2, 'Class'] = 1
    plagiarism_df.loc[plagiarism_df['Category']==3, 'Class'] = 1
    plagiarism_df.loc[plagiarism_df['Category']==-1,'Class'] = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not modifying the DataFrame, `replace` returns a new DataFrame, you have to assign it:
`plagiarism_df =  plagiarism_df.replace({'Category': { 'non': 0, 'heavy': 1, 'light': 2, 'cut': 3, 'orig': -1 }})`

or use que param `inplace = True` which modifies the DataFrame object like this:

`plagiarism_df.replace({'Category':{ 'non': 0, 'heavy': 1, 'light': 2, 'cut': 3, 'orig': -1}}, inplace=True)`

Answer (score 0):

alternately you can use map function and then apply a lambda to get the desired result:
`plagiarism_df['Category'] = plagiarism_df['Category'].map({ 'non': 0, 'heavy': 1, 'light': 2, 'cut': 3, 'orig': -1})`

`plagiarism_df['Class'] = plagiarism_df['Category'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x in [1,2,3,-1] else 0)`